# How does memory mapping a file have significant performance increases over the standard I/O system calls?

Tags: linux, performance, io, virtual-memory, mmap

Operating System Concepts says

> Consider a sequential read of a ﬁle on disk **using the standard
> system calls open(), read(), and write()**. **Each ﬁle access requires
> a system call and disk access**.
>
> Alternatively, we can use the virtual memory techniques discussed so
> far to treat ﬁle I/O as routine memory accesses. This approach, known
> as
> **memory mapping a ﬁle**, allows a part of the virtual address space to be logically associated with the ﬁle. As we shall see, this can
> lead to **signiﬁcant performance increases**. Memory mapping a ﬁle is
> accomplished by mapping a disk block to a page (or pages) in memory.
> Initial access to the ﬁle proceeds through ordinary demand paging,
> resulting in a page fault. However, a page-sized portion of the ﬁle is
> read from the ﬁle system into a physical page (some systems may opt to
> read in more than a page-sized chunk of memory at a time). Subsequent
> reads and writes to the ﬁle are handled as routine memory accesses.
> Manipulating ﬁles through memory rather than incurring the overhead of
> using the read() and write() system calls simpliﬁes and speeds up ﬁle
> access and usage.

Could you analyze the performance of memory mapped file?

If I am correct, memory mapping file works as following. It takes a system call to create  a memory mapping.
Then when it accesses the mapped memory, page faults happen. Page faults  also have overhead.

How does memory mapping a file have significant performance increases over the standard I/O system calls?

Comment: This link is helpful: https://www.programmersought.com/article/1218984627/  . In a word, mmap has a better performance because it copies data only once, but standard IO copies data twice.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Memory mapping a file directly avoids copying buffers which happen with `read()` and `write()` calls. Calls to `read()` and `write()` include a pointer to buffer in process' address space where the data is stored. Kernel has to copy the data to/from those locations. Using `mmap()` maps the file to process' address space, so the process can address the file directly and no copies are required.

There is also no system call overhead when accessing memory mapped file after the initial call if the file is loaded to memory at initial `mmap()`. If a page of the mapped file is not in memory, access will generate a fault and require kernel to load the page to memory. Reading a large block with `read()` can be faster than `mmap()` in such cases, if `mmap()` would generate significant number of faults to read the file. (It is possible to advise kernel in advance with [`madvise()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) so that the kernel may load the pages in advance before access).

For more details, there is related question on Stack Overflow: [*mmap() vs. reading blocks*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45972/8270535)

Comment: Thanks. What is "copying buffers which happen with read() and write() calls"? Why does memory mapping a file not have it?

Comment: "Calls to read() and write() include a pointer to buffer in process' address space where the data is stored. "  Memory-mapped file doesn't have such a buffer, but instead has a memory region mapped to a file. So are they not equivalent?

Comment: Not exactly. The kernel may cache the file, so read()/write() calls copy from the cache to process' buffers. With mmap() process can access those (cache) pages directly.

Comment: Thanks. in`void *mmap(void *addr, size_t len, int prot, int ﬂag, int fd, off_t off );`, the `addr` argument lets us specify the address where we want the mapped region to start.   (1) "Calls to read() and write() include a pointer to buffer in process' address space where the data is stored. "  Isn't `addr` argument of `mmap()` "a pointer to buffer in process' address space where the data is stored"?

Comment: (2)" `mmap()` process can access those (cache) pages directly".  Doesn't `mmap()` access  the mapped region pointed by `addr` argument of `mmap()` "? Isn't the mapped region part of the process address space?

Comment: Yes, the file is mapped directly in the process' address space.

Answer (score 18):

First, in most IO operations the characteristics of the underlying storage hardware dominates the performance.  A poorly-configured RAID5 array of twenty-nine  S-L-O-W 5400 rpm SATA disks on a slow, memory-starved system using S/W RAID with mismatched block sizes and misaligned file systems is going to give you poor performance compared to a properly configured and aligned SSD RAID 1+0 on a high-performance controller despite any software tuning you might try.

But the only way `mmap()` can be significantly faster is if you read the same data more than once **and** the data you read doesn't get paged out between reads because of memory pressure.

Memory map steps:

1. System call to create virtual mappings - very expensive
2. Process accesses memory for the first time, causing a page fault - expensive (and may need to be repeated if paged out)
3. Process actually reads the memory

If the process only does steps 2 and 3 once for each bit of data read, or the data gets dropped from memory because of memory pressure, `mmap()` is going to be slower.

`read()` steps:

1. System call copies data from disk to page cache (may or may not page fault, data may already be in page cache causing this to be skipped)
2. Data copied from page cache to process memory (may or may not page fault)

Memory mapping is only going to beat this performance-wise because of that extra copy from the page cache to process memory.  But a mere copy of a page of memory (or less) has to be done multiple times to beat the cost of setting up the mapping - probably.  How many times depends on your system.  Memory bandwidth, how your entire system is being used, everything.  For example, if the time used by the kernel's memory management to set up the mapping wouldn't have been used by any other process anyway, the cost of creating the mapping really isn't very high.  Conversely, if you have a lot of processing on your system that involves a lot of virtual memory mapping creation/destruction (i.e., lots of short-lived processes) the impact of memory mapped IO might be significant.

Then there's `read()` using direct IO:

1. System call to read from disk into process memory space.  (may or may not cause a page fault)

Direct IO reads are pretty much impossible to beat performance-wise.  But you have to really tune your IO patterns to your hardware to maximize performance.

Note that a process can pretty much control if reading data causes a page fault for the buffer the process is using to read.

So, is memory-mapped file access faster?  Maybe it is, maybe it isn't.

**It depends on your access pattern(s).**  Along with your hardware and everything else in your IO path(s).

If you're streaming a 30 GB video file on a machine with 4 GB of RAM, and you never go back and reread any of the data, memory-mapping the file is probably the **worst** way to read it.

Conversely, if you have a 100 MB lookup table for some data that you randomly access billions and billions of times in your processing and enough memory that the file never gets paged out, memory mapping will crush all other access methods.

**One huge advantage of memory-mapped files**

Memory mapping files has a huge advantage over other forms of IO:  code simplicity.  It's really hard to beat the simplicity of accessing a file as if it's in memory.  And most times, the difference in performance between memory-mapping a file and doing discrete IO operations isn't all that much anyway.